# Can't insert checkboxes into mysql database

Tags: php

I have these checkboxes that I am trying to (ultimately concat two together and) insert into a database. I've tried several ways and have searched through many pages, but my page keeps breaking when I try to insert. I'm not actually getting an error in my apache log, but a message is triggered that makes me believe it's some kind of sql error (the else statement at the end, which is a check if the query affected any rows). The error isn't thrown until I add the foreach and additional awards to the query .

Here is the form section

```
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor" />Castle Connolly Top U.S. Doctor</label>
            <!-- <input type="text" name="check_year" value="<php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/> -->
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Vitals Patients Choice"/>Vitals Patient's Choice</label>
            <!--<input type="text" name="check_year" value="<php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/> -->
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Vitals Compassionate Doctor"/>Vital's Compassionate Doctor Recognition</label>
            <!--<input type="text" name="check_year" value="<php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/> -->
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" Value = "Super Doctor"/>Super Doctor</label>
            <!--<input type="text" name="check_year" value <php echo decode_text($check_year);?>"/> -->
```

inserting

```
$additional_awards = '';
$check_list = $_POST['check_list'];


        foreach($check_list as $check)
        {
            $additional_awards .= $check.", ";
        }

// insert new user
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO docflight_doctors (

                    email,
                    user_name,
                    user_password,
                    additional_awards,
                    preferred_language,
                    date_created,
                    registered_from_ip,
                    last_logged_ip,
                    is_active,
                    is_removed,
                    comments,
                    registration_code )
                VALUES(
                    \''.encode_text($email).'\',
                    \''.encode_text($user_name).'\',
                    \''.$user_password.'\',
                    \''.$additional_awards.'\',
                    \''.Application::Get('lang').'\',
                    \''.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'\',
                    \''.$user_ip.'\',
                    \'\',
                    '.$is_active.',
                    0,
                    \'\',
                    \''.$registration_code.'\')';

        if(database_void_query($sql) > 0){

 /// do other stuff
 else{
            ///echo mysql_error();
            $msg = draw_important_message(_CREATING_ACCOUNT_ERROR, false);
```

FIXED,    \''.$user_password.'\', should have been  '.$user_password.', for some reason ....

Comment: Why are you naming `check_list[]`? Try getting the checked checkboxes with JS and sending the values to PHP.

Comment: what happens if you `echo  $additional_awards`?

Comment: when I echo $additional_awards it shows what I initially set it to and when try $check_list it shows 1

Comment: I got rid of the isset around $_POST['check_list'] and now echoing both shows what I want, but for some reason the sql query is still failing